# Ubuntu: install "cannot create directory" - permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

While I was trying to install `intltool` on Ubuntu I got this:

```
install: cannot create directory /usr/share/doc/intltool-0.35.5: Permission denied
```

I got this error after I typed:

```
make install
```

and also:

```
make install &&
install -v -m644 -D doc/I18N-HOWTO \
    /usr/share/doc/intltool-0.35.5/I18N-HOWTO
```

and I also tried:

```
sudo make install &&
install -v -m644 -D doc/I18N-HOWTO \
    /usr/share/doc/intltool-0.35.5/I18N-HOWTO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you try to install this from source? Use the Ubuntu packages and the system will keep them up to date:

```
sudo aptitude install intltool
```

Comment: Oops. You're right.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try:

```
sudo make install && sudo install -v -m644 -D doc/I18N-HOWTO \ 
/usr/share/doc/intltool-0.35.5/I18N-HOWTO
```

sudo executes the immediately following command as superuser you need to put it in front of both commands.